Facing compilation error while Building project on Jenkins
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/ProgramData/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/flipkart-automation/src/main/java/com/flipkart/FlipkartAutomation.java:[7,30] package org.testng.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/ProgramData/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/flipkart-automation/src/main/java/com/flipkart/FlipkartAutomation.java:[8,30] package org.testng.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/ProgramData/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/flipkart-automation/src/main/java/com/flipkart/FlipkartAutomation.java:[12,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BeforeMethod
  location: class com.flipkart.FlipkartAutomation
[ERROR] /C:/ProgramData/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/flipkart-automation/src/main/java/com/flipkart/FlipkartAutomation.java:[19,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AfterMethod
  location: class com.flipkart.FlipkartAutomation

As im providing all needed requirements on pom.xml file regarding testng requirements, but then also it giving me error

Please provide the mvn command you executed, full maven command output and pom.xml snippet where you have defined testng dependency.

It looks like you are using TestNG annotation in your production code src/main/java/<package> instead of src/test/java/<package> or you have to change the scope of your testng from <scope>test</scope> or remove the scope (which means <scope>compile</scope>...
